# MVC Core. Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am passing in my view this model

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    public List<CommentModel> commentModels { get; set; }
    public BlogPostLayoutModel blogPostLayoutModel { get; set; }
    public CommentModel commentModel { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

CommentModel class

```
 public class CommentModel
{
    public int IDComment { get; set; }
    public int IDPost { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public static CommentModel CommentToCommentModel(Comment comment)
    {
        CommentModel commentModel = new CommentModel();
        commentModel.IDComment = comment.IDComment;
        commentModel.IDPost = comment.IDPost;
        commentModel.Username = comment.Username;
        commentModel.Content = comment.Content;
        return commentModel;
    }

    public static List<CommentModel> CommentsToCommentModels(List<Comment> comments)
    {
        List<CommentModel> commentModels = new List<CommentModel>();
        foreach (var comment in comments)
        {
            CommentModel commentModel = new CommentModel();
            commentModel.IDComment = comment.IDComment;
            commentModel.IDPost = comment.IDPost;
            commentModel.Username = comment.Username;
            commentModel.Content = comment.Content;
            commentModels.Add(commentModel);
        }
        return commentModels;
    }
}
```

And my view, where the error is thrown (fifth line)

```
<form asp-action="AddComment">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        @{ var pageNumber = Model.pageNumber;
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => pageNumber)
            int IDPost = Model.blogPostLayoutModel.IDPost;
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.commentModel.IDPost == IDPost)
        }

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="commentModel.Username" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="commentModel.Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="commentModel.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label">Comment</label>
                <textarea asp-for="commentModel.Content" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="commentModel.Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have searched for the error, but seems like it's mostly people trying to return a value from a method and getting told to pass the value to a local variable and then put that local variable inside the tag helper, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

And also  blogPostLayoutModel.IDPost is defined as

```
 public int IDPost { get; set; }
```

EDIT: My commentModel was null, so that was the problem.

Working form

```
<form asp-action="AddComment">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        @{
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.pageNumber)
            Model.commentModel.IDPost = Model.blogPostLayoutModel.IDPost;
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.commentModel.IDPost)
        }
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="commentModel.Username" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="commentModel.Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="commentModel.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label">Comment</label>
                <textarea asp-for="commentModel.Content" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="commentModel.Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Well sorry to be a student trying to learn mvc. I'm trying to pass it to the controller, so i can navigate back to the post with the given ID.

Comment: first, your view is a template.  It prints what you put in it literally to the web browser.  So it's literally going to send the text `int IDPost = Model.blogPostLayoutModel.IDPost;` to your web browser (unless prefixed by an @).  Second, you don't put html helpers within angle brackets like that.  The angle brackets are generated automatically.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Updated the code, so it makes sense.

Comment: Next, you can only post back values from a form field if it's inside of a form element.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Should've added at start, that the code is inside the form.

Comment: Next, you can't use the syntax with the == inside a helper lambda.  You should just do `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.blogPostLayoutModel.IDPost)`

Comment: `EDIT: My commentModel was null, so that was the problem.` that may have been **a** problem, but was not **the** problem.  the error in your title was caused by the == in your HiddenFor

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yes, but that was the first problem. The == was the next one which shouldnt belong here, i guess?